# WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: java, xml, logging, console, log4j2

I use `log4j2.xml` to write my logs into a local file in my Maven project. I've installed the last dependencies for present day `<version>2.20.0</version>)` in pom.xml.
My `log4j2.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
            <TimeFilter start="01:00:00" end="07:00:00" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>

            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My dependencies in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I start my main method logs successfully be written in a file, but I get the message in IntelliJ IDEA console:

> WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate
> plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

How can I resolve the problem?  just want to stop appearing the message in console.

Comment: What is the issue exactly that you feel that you need to solve?

Comment: @aled just want to remove printing "WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release" in console

Comment: Is that the full literal message? Are there more lines or details?

Comment: @aled The full message is:

`WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: Just install jmeter 5.4 and it will solve your issue. Link to download jmeter:
https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This warning is caused by using the `packages` attribute of the `Configuration` element in the log4j2.xml file, because it has been [deprecated](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax). Removing that attribute should prevent the message from appearing.

Comment: Removing is an option when the packages attribute is blank. What if it is used, as in my case, to specify the packages with my custom plugins I want log4j to scan and add?
I didn't manage to find any alternatives for this deprecated way of addition of the custom plugins.

Comment: @contrapost you have to use one of the non-deprecated methods described in the documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html

Comment: This is not fixing my issue any other work around ?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to removing `packages` from your configuration, to fix this issue you have to add `log4j-core` as an annotation processor.

If you're using Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0")
}
```

As [@aled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721855/aled) points out, instructions for Maven are in the docs: [Log4j 2 Plugins](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html)